# PYTHON: Searching two files for common lines and collecting their contents into set

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a task to compare two comma separated files. If the first two columns exist in both files, then I have to collect the remaining columns into set from both the files in my results.

If I have the following two files:

### a.txt

```
1,2,3,4
2,4,7,5
3,8,6,7
4,9,5,6
3,8,7,2
```

### b.txt

```
1,2,4,6
2,3,6,5
3,8,9,2
4,9,6,9
3,5,2,3
6,2,7,3
```

I want to get the results:

```
1,2(3,4,4,6)
3,8(6,7,7,2,9,2)
4,9(5,6,6,9)
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement it? especially as the files maybe large and not fit in the available memory of my computer.

The following is my implement.

```
KEYNOTFOUND = '<KEYNOTFOUND>'

class dict_cls(object):

    @staticmethod
    def dict_diff(first, second):
        diff = {}

        for key in first.keys():
            if (not second.has_key(key)):
                diff[key] = (first[key], KEYNOTFOUND)
            elif (first[key] != second[key]):
                diff[key] = (first[key], second[key])

        for key in second.keys():
            if (not first.has_key(key)):
                diff[key] = (KEYNOTFOUND, second[key])

        return diff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict1 = {(1,2):(3,4),(2,4):(7,5),(3,8):(6,7),(4,9):(5,6),(3,8):(7,2)}
    dict2 = {(1,2):(4,6),(2,3):(6,5),(3,8):(9,2),(4,9):(6,9),(3,5):(2,3),(6,2):(7,3)}
    print dict_cls.dict_diff(dict1, dict2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime


class FindCommKey(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.combine = {}
        self.counter = {}
        self.result = {}

    def find_common_key(self, target_file):
        with open(target_file, 'r+') as file_handler:
            for line in file_handler:
                print(line, end='')
                __line = list(map(int, line.strip().split(',')))
                key, value = tuple(__line[:2]), __line[2:]
                if key in self.combine:
                    self.combine[key] = self.combine[key] + value
                else:
                    self.combine[key] = value

                if key in self.counter:
                    self.counter[key] = self.counter[key] + 1
                else:
                    self.counter[key] = 1

        for k1, v1 in self.counter.items():
            if v1 >= 2:
                self.result[k1] = self.combine[k1]
        print()
        return self.result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ['ds1.txt', 'ds2.txt']
    print("Started at: {}{}".format(datetime.datetime.now(), '\n'))
    print('Initial data:')
    fck = FindCommKey()
    for f in files:
        fck.find_common_key(f)

    print("Write to dic finished at: {}{}".format(datetime.datetime.now(), '\n'))

    print('Result set:')
    for k, v in fck.result.items():
        print(','.join(map(str, k)), tuple(v))
    print("{}Finished at: {}".format('\n', datetime.datetime.now()))
```